# Session Data lost after refresh browser in Laravel app

Tags: laravel, session

In my laravel application i just want to store input data in a session and use it every where But the data is lost when i refresh the browser.

my controller:

```
public function usepoint(Request $request){
    $fdata = $request->input_point;
    Session::put('test', $fdata); 
    return Redirect()->back();
}
```

view page:

```
 <p>use Point : 

 <form method="get" action="{{url('cart/usepoint')}}">

 <input class="" type="" name="input_point" value="" style="width:40%"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary ">use</button> </p>

 </form>

 <p>Session data:</p>
 <input class="del_point" type="text" name="del_point" value="{{Session::get('test')}}"  style="width: 40%" readonly>
```

route:

```
Route::get('cart/usepoint','cartController@usepoint');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your `config/session.php` configuration:

```
 'expire_on_close' => false,
```

If the problem still occurs, check if you have any `dd()`'s in your application. Apparently, according to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-do-sessions-disappear-on-refresh), `dd()` makes it so your session doesn't get stored correctly and you can't read data from that session.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have no dd() in my application. At first time i get data in view but if i reload again it lost the session data. plz help me.

Comment: struggled hours on this, I was trying to display my data with dd()... after removing them everything was fine...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to pass data to view using with() method inside controller:

```
$fdata = $request->input_point;
return redirect()->back()->with('success', $fdata );
```